# How to remove a sub string from a string in java

Tags: java, string

I need to pre-process a string and remove some words from it. what i am looking for is something like:-

```
private static final String[] stopWords = { "is", "on", "of", "with"};
String s1 = "Tiger is Mammal with sharp teeth";
System.out.println("s1 = " + s1);  // "Tiger is Mammal with sharp teeth"
s1.remove(stopWords);  //remove should remove 'is' and 'with'  from s1
System.out.println("s1 = " + s1); // "Tiger Mammal sharp teeth"
```

I am new to programming so please do consider.

Comment: First of all there is a documentation. So I suggest you to take a look at it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Sure sir i will look at documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\b(is|on|of|with)\\b","");
```

That will delete the words, but leave the spaces on both sides, so after that you might want to replace the double spaces with singles:

```
s1 = s1.replace("  "," ");
```